# Koin tests - DependencyResolutionException

Tags: android, unit-testing, koin

I have multiple test classes with multiple tests in each class. 
In each class I want to make sure that I get fresh test dependencies for each test. So I prepare my tests like this:

```
    @Before
fun initTest() {
    loadKoinModules(listOf(module {
        scope(TEST_SCOPE, override = true) { Dependency1() }
        scope(TEST_SCOPE, override = true) { Dependency2() }
    }))
    getKoin().createScope(TEST_SCOPE)
}

@After
fun shutdown() {
    getKoin().getScope(TEST_SCOPE).close()
}
```

And it works very well when I run only the tests in that particular test class.

But when I run all my tests in the same time, and if multiple test classes have the same dependencies in their modules, I get an Exception like this:

```
org.koin.error.DependencyResolutionException: Multiple definitions found - Koin can't choose between :
Scope [name='Dependency2',class='package.Dependency2']
Scope [name='Dependency2',class='package.Dependency2']
Check your modules definition, use inner modules visibility or definition names.
```

So I fixed this by simply calling `stopKoin()` at the end of my shutdown method.

And so far I haven't noticed that my tests run much slower. So basically my question is: is this the preferred way to use Koin in my tests? Am I missing something or not using Koin Properly ?

I realize that this is more a code review/advice question than a real problem but I think this might still be useful to others.

Thanks